# Как правильно перевести проект на YIi 2, чтобы работал на PHP 7+

Tags: php, yii2

Всем доброго времени суток.
Знаю, что много инфы по этому поводу в интернете, но так и не смог нормально реализовать.
До этого проект был на 5.6, перевел его на php 7.2
И выскочила ошибка

> Cannot use 'Object' as class name as it is reserved

Подключены такие зависимости, но все равно выскакивает ошибка

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.13",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.7",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0",
    "sirian/yandex-market-language-parser": "^3.0",
    "pug-php/pug": "^2.6",
    "innologica/yii2-vue": "dev-master",
    "zelenin/yii2-slug-behavior": "~1.5.1",
    "yiidoc/yii2-redactor": "*",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
    "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
    "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1",
    "codeception/specify": "~0.4.3"
},
```

Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: ну дак, найти то можно в какой части используется `Object`? сам `2.0.13` переведен на `BaseObject`

Comment: Как найти в каком месте используется Object. Подскажите?

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день.

> Чтобы Yii работал с PHP 7.2, мы переименовали класс. yii\base\Object помечен как deprecated. Используйте yii\base\BaseObject. Версии Yii 2 до 2.0.13 не совместимы с PHP 7.2.
>   Вот [ссылка](https://habrahabr.ru/post/341614/) на лист изменений

Переименуйте Object в BaseObject.
В PhpStorm кликните по имени класса и нажмите F6. Отметьте необходимые чекбоксы и нажмите "OK"

Comment: у автора `2.0.13-2.1`, проблема в других пакетах.

Answer (score 0):

Переименуйте класс Object в BaseObject, так как 
https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.other-reserved-words.php